# How to group elements in python by n elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, grouping

Given a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` and a specified chunk size (say 3), how can I get a list of chunks `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]`?

Answer (score 61):

Well, the brute force answer is:

```
subList = [theList[n:n+N] for n in range(0, len(theList), N)]
```

where `N` is the group size (3 in your case):

```
>>> theList = list(range(10))
>>> N = 3
>>> subList = [theList[n:n+N] for n in range(0, len(theList), N)]
>>> subList
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

If you want a fill value, you can do this right before the list comprehension:

```
tempList = theList + [fill] * N
subList = [tempList[n:n+N] for n in range(0, len(theList), N)]
```

Example:

```
>>> fill = 99
>>> tempList = theList + [fill] * N
>>> subList = [tempList[n:n+N] for n in range(0, len(theList), N)]
>>> subList
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 99, 99]]
```

Answer (score 41):

You can use the grouper function from the [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the itertools documentation:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks.

    >>> grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x')
    ['ABC', 'DEF', 'Gxx']
    """
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to do this. However, a more helpful answer would link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks/434411#434411 , since it includes some discussion as to why this works.

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
a = range(1,10)
n = 3
out = [a[k:k+n] for k in range(0, len(a), n)]
```

Comment: Did you test this?  I don't think `[[1, 4, 7], [4], [7]]` is the desired output.

Comment: Remove the extra `:` in the `[]` operation.  It's the same answer as the first part of mine.

Answer (score 5):

See examples at the bottom of the itertools docs: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools

You want the "grouper" method, or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = [L[3*i:(3*i)+3] for i in range((len(L)/3) +1)]
if not answer[-1]:
    answer = answer[:-1]
```