# Grab x,y,z coordinates from the list

Tags: python

```
counter = 0    
cord =[1,2,21,12,2,44,5,13,15,5,19,21,5]
for i in cord:
    if (counter ==0):
        x=i
    if (counter ==1):
        y =i
    if (counter ==2): 
        z= i
    counter = counter+1
print(x,y,z)

Output
1 2 21
```

But I want output in pairs of 3.
for example- (1,2,21) (12,2,44) like wise

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` and slice:

```
>>> list(zip(cord[::3], cord[1::3], cord[2::3]))
[(1, 2, 21), (12, 2, 44), (5, 13, 15), (5, 19, 21)]
```

Printing

```
lst = zip(cord[::3], cord[1::3], cord[2::3])
print(*lst, sep='\n')
(1, 2, 21)
(12, 2, 44)
(5, 13, 15)
(5, 19, 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[tuple(cord[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(cord),3)]
# [(1, 2, 21), (12, 2, 44), (5, 13, 15), (5, 19, 21), (5,)]

print(*[tuple(cord[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(cord),3)])
# (1, 2, 21) (12, 2, 44) (5, 13, 15) (5, 19, 21) (5,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method is to just iterate in threes, see below:

```py
cord = [1,2,21,12,2,44,5,13,15,5,19,21,5]

for i in range(0, len(cord), 3):
    x = cord[i]
    y = cord[i + 1]
    z = cord[i + 2]

    print(x, y, z)
```

For a better answer that'll preserve the list, see [How to group elements in python by n elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998427/how-to-group-elements-in-python-by-n-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit tedious but can be useful.

```
def divide(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
for x in divide(cord,3):
    print(x)
```

So the thing is, here you will also get a list with one element and process it further. (Maybe you can filter as per length or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

You should save it to list or tuple with 3 pairs:

```
counter = 0    
cord =[1,2,21,12,2,44,5,13,15,5,19,21,5]
point=[]
for i in cord:  
    point.append(i)
    counter = counter+1
    if counter==3:
        print(point)        
        point=[]
        counter=0
```